# Mongoose right promise rejection handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, mongoose, promise

I'm bit fighting with promise pattern in nodeJS

I'm looking for user in db and then saving new entity with user reference, but when user is not in db, I should return rejection, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

is there way how to do it more nicely?

btw: sorry, coffeescript :-[

```
User.findOne({'fbId':userData.me.id}).exec().then((doc)->
  if !doc? then return new Promise (resolve,reject)->reject(404)

  video = new Video({
    user:doc
    state: "queue"
    createdAt: new Date()
  })

  video.save().exec()
)
```

Comment: Are you using ES6 Promises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `throw` inside `then` callbacks to reject them. Or, instead of using the `Promise` constructor like that, you might also use [`Promise.reject(404)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject).

```
User.findOne
  fbId:userData.me.id 
.exec().then (doc)->
  if !doc? 
    throw new Error 404

  video = new Video
    user: doc
    state: "queue"
    createdAt: new Date
  video.save().exec()
```