# How to protect a route with a referrer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to protect a route in my node.js application such that if the user wants to go to the page `/post` they have to come from `/blog`. If the user comes from anything other than `/blog` they are to be redirected to `/`. I have the following code that uses the http referrer

```
let ref = req.headers.referer;

if ((ref === undefined) || (!ref.includes('blog'))) {
  res.redirect('/')
}
```

It seems to work well if I console.log for testing but if I do res.redirect, I get the error

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

How can I use the referrer to protect the route.

Should there be any other way of accomplishing this without using referring: all suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That error means you're placing that code *after* calling `res.send()` or a similar command instead of before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERR\_HTTP\_HEADERS\_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122272/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: @koos, basically referer will return only full path then how you will check using includes

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In your **app.js** file include this.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/',(req, res, next)=>{
  res.send('Ready')
});

app.get('/test',(req, res, next)=>{
  res.send('Ready')
});

// Below (*) will consider unwanted urls
app.use('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/')
});


app.listen(4000);
```

FYI, If you try **demo.com/unkownurl** will redirect to root like **demo.com/**