# After http POST response, cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs, formidable

First I apologize for the typos, I'm Brazilian

I visited the question below, but it didn't help me solve my problem

[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122272/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

I have a method that I call from the route `localhost:4000/returnvalues` 
on the first request, it works as expected

but in the next one, it returns the following error

```
_http_outgoing.js:526
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set'); ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

my code

```
module.exports = app => {

const formidable = require('formidable')
const path = require('path')
const folder = path.join("C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop", 'files')
const fs = require('fs')
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
    uploadDir: folder,
    keepExtensions: true
})

const returnvalues = async (req, res) => {
    form.parse(req, (_, fields, files) => {
        app.api.readFile.readFiles(files.Teste.path).then(values => {
            res.status(200).send(values)
           })
       })
   }

  return { returnvalues }
}
```

I tried unsuccessfully to use

```
return res.status(200).send(values)
```

this method returns me an object read from an excel spreadsheet

[error from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuLNT.png)
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXlGP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into the same error as you. 
If you put your form variable

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
    uploadDir: folder,
    keepExtensions: true
})
```

inside your `returnvalues` function, it should work.