# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT when sending progressbar update (node.js/express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, progress-bar, tesseract.js

I'm trying to make a progress bar to monitor a Tesseract.recognize() call but when I try sending an update to change the progress bar I get this error:

```
[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

This is what's running in the routes.js file:

```
Tesseract.recognize(
    '/app/'+statistic.path_out_new
    ,'eng'
    , { logger: m => {
        console.log(m);
         res.render('pages/uploadPicture.ejs', {
              user : req.user
              ,progress : m
         });   
    } }
)

.then(({ data: { text } }) => {
    res.render('pages/uploadPage.ejs', {
        user : req.user
        ,progress : text
    });  
});
```

Here is the relevant part of the HTML from the EJS template, uploadPage.ejs:

```
<section><div></div><progress value="<%=progress.progress%>" text="<%=progress.status%>" /></section>
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122272/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) and I think the problem is caused by sending multiple headers every time there is an update to the progress bar, but how do I send information about how the function is progressing to the user (so that the progress bar updates) without sending a header, too? I tried res.write() as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) but that let to the progress bar page timing out, not updating.

Comment: Hi, could you please give some feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't only through `res`: `res.render` purpose is to send all the result at once and then close the HTTP request (connection could be kept open for keep alive). The best choice to show the progress of a job is a WebSocket.

A little improved version of your code, without using WebSockets could be:

```
var status = {}

app.get("/update/:id", (req, res) => res.json(status[req.params.id]));

app.get("/tesseract", (req, res) => {
  const id = ... ; // here generate a unique job id

  Tesseract.recognize('/app/'+statistic.path_out_new, 'eng', { logger: m => {
    // here update status[id] reflecting the progress
  }}).then(data => {
    // here update status[id] reflecting the end of the job
  });

  res.render("pages/uploadPage.ejs", { id, user: req.user });
});
```

The page rendered should call (under a setTimeout) `/update/${id}` in ajax to get the updated status util it represents a job completed status.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for this! I will try to implement it. I was hoping there was something easier, but I guess not :) I wonder how they do it for the progressbar on the main tesseract.js site https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/