# MS Teams Task task modules from bots failing with 501 error

Tags: microsoft-teams

We've been using Botbuilder.js version 4.15.0 for our Teams Bot.

When user invoke task module using `task/fetch`, Bot calls `handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch` handler and respond with 501 because `invokeResponse` is `undefined` (see [botFrameworkAdapter](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/cc49139276aa9cda60ea12da3c8583845b05cee2/libraries/botbuilder/src/botFrameworkAdapter.ts#L1241)) and right after that it tries to respond with 200 and `req.body` with actual `task` which leads to this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Messenger Bot:

```js
export class MessengerBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
      this.handleMessage(context);
      await next();
    });
  }

  async handleMessage(context: TurnContext) {
    const activity = MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
      $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
      version: '1.5',
      type: 'AdaptiveCard',
      body: [
        {
          type: 'TextBlock',
          text: 'Task Module Invocation from Adaptive Card',
          weight: 'bolder',
          size: 3
        }
      ],
      actions: [{
        type: 'Action.Submit',
        title: 'Open',
        data: {
          msteams: { type: 'task/fetch' },
          data: {
            foo: 'bar'
          }
        }
      }]
    }));
    activity.summary = 'Open URL';
    await context.sendActivity(activity);
  }

  async handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch(context: TurnContext, taskModuleRequest: TaskModuleRequest): Promise<TaskModuleResponse> {
    const url = 'https://some valid domain to navigate to'; // Domain included in "validDomains" and use HTTPS
    return {
      task: {
        type: 'continue',
        value: {
          title: 'Create Ticket',
          height: 700,
          width: 700,
          fallbackUrl: url,
          url: url
        },
      },
    };
  }

  async handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit(context: TurnContext, taskModuleRequest: TaskModuleRequest): Promise<TaskModuleResponse> {
    return {
      task: {
        type: 'message',
        value: 'Thanks!'
      }
    };
  }
}
```

How can I find out the cause of this error? Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: The "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. When you see this error, try to look for anything that tries to send a header after some of the body has already been written. Please check the following threads where similar issue has been reported - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122272/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. The problem was `processActivity` method was called twice.