# Inversify The error middleware throws unhandled error for first container config and last router

Tags: node.js, express, inversifyjs

### Expected Behavior

The unhandler error captures should pass through the error middleware and should send the proper error message. All route should behave same using by passing error to error middleware

### Current Behavior

For any first container config that is imported and its last router is giving this error:

```
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)
```

### Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

**controller.ts**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';
import { BaseController } from '@sn/server';
import { AppError } from '@sn/core';
import { logDecorator } from '@sn/shared';

@injectable()
export class GetMetaController extends BaseController {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  @logDecorator()
  public async executeImpl(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      throw new Error('Throw some error');
      // return this.ok<any>(response, { user: 1 });
    } catch (err: any) {
      return this.fail(response, new AppError.UnexpectedError(err), next);
    }
  }
}
```

**route.ts**

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { inject } from 'inversify';
import { controller, httpGet } from 'inversify-express-utils';
import { ApiPath } from 'swagger-express-ts';
import TYPES from '@ioc/constant/Types';
import { GetRefVersionController } from '../controller/GetRefVersionController';
import { GetMetaController } from '../controller/GetMetaController';

@ApiPath({
  name: 'RefVersions',
  path: '/refVersion'
})
@controller('/refVersion')
export abstract class RefVersionRouters {
  constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.GetRefVersionController)
    private readonly _getRefVersionController: GetRefVersionController,

    @inject(TYPES.GetMetaController)
    private readonly _getMeta: GetMetaController
  ) {}

  @httpGet('/version')
  public async getAllRefVersion(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) {
    return this._getRefVersionController.execute(request, response, next);
  }

  @httpGet('/meta')
  public async getMeta(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) {
    return this._getMeta.execute(request, response, next);
  }
}
```

**module_config.ts**

```
import { AsyncContainerModule, interfaces } from 'inversify';

import { errorHandler } from '@core/error/ErrorHandler';
import TYPES from '@ioc/constant/Types';

import { RefVersionRouters } from './infrastructure/routers/RefVersionRouter';

import { GetRefVersionController } from './infrastructure/controller/GetRefVersionController';
import { GetMetaController } from './infrastructure/controller/GetMetaController';

const SystemConfigContainer = new AsyncContainerModule(
  async (bind: interfaces.Bind) => {
    try {
      RefVersionRouters;

      bind<GetRefVersionController>(TYPES.GetRefVersionController)
        .to(GetRefVersionController)
        .inRequestScope();
      bind<GetMetaController>(TYPES.GetMetaController)
        .to(GetMetaController)
        .inRequestScope();
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      errorHandler.handleError('SystemIOC Error', err as Error);
    }
  }
);

export { SystemConfigContainer };
```

**Ioc_config.ts**

```
import { Container } from 'inversify';

import { errorHandler } from '@core/error/ErrorHandler';
import TYPES from './constant/Types';
import { SystemConfigContainer } from '@system-module/SystemIocConfig';
import { CheckConfigContainer } from '../module/check/CheckConfig';
import { UserConfigContainer } from '@user-module/UserIocConfig';

const InversifyConfigContainer = async () => {
  const container = new Container();

  try {
    container.loadAsync(SystemConfigContainer);
    container.loadAsync(UserConfigContainer);
    container.loadAsync(CheckConfigContainer);
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    errorHandler.handleError('IOC Error', err as Error);
  }

  return container;
};

export { InversifyConfigContainer };
```

AppServer.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
/* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
require('source-map-support').install();
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { InversifyExpressServer } from 'inversify-express-utils';
import { ExpressMiddleware, errorMiddleware } from './../middleware';
import { logger } from '@sn/shared';
// import { envConfig } from './config';
// import { ExitProcess } from './core/utils/ExitProcess';

dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

export const appServer = async (config: any): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const server = new InversifyExpressServer(config, null, {
      rootPath: '/api/v1'
    });

    /* Adding middleware to express server */
    server.setConfig((app) => {
      new ExpressMiddleware(app);
    });

    server.setErrorConfig(errorMiddleware);
    const serverInstance = server.build();

    serverInstance.listen(port, () => {
      logger.info(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:${port}/`);
    });

    // ExitProcess(server);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Error in SERVER', err);
  }
};
```

**MainAppServer.ts:**

```
import 'module-alias/register';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { InversifyConfigContainer } from '@ioc/IocConfig';

import sourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support';
import { logger } from '@sn/shared';
import { appServer } from '@sn/server';

sourceMapSupport.install();

const expressApp = (async (): Promise<void> => {
  /* Setting up IoC */
  try {
    const containerConfig = await InversifyConfigContainer();
    await appServer(containerConfig);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Error', err);
  }
})();

expressApp;
```

### Context

If import is like this:

```
import { SystemConfigContainer } from '@system-module/SystemIocConfig';
import { CheckConfigContainer } from '../module/check/CheckConfig';
import { UserConfigContainer } from '@user-module/UserIocConfig';
```

Here the last route of import { SystemConfigContainer } from '@system-module/SystemIocConfig'; throws the error of request already sent

If we change the import like this

```
import { CheckConfigContainer } from '../module/check/CheckConfig';
import { SystemConfigContainer } from '@system-module/SystemIocConfig';
import { UserConfigContainer } from '@user-module/UserIocConfig';
```

Then last route of import { CheckConfigContainer } from '../module/check/CheckConfig'; throws the errror:

All other route works perfectly

### Your Environment

- "inversify": "^6.0.1",
- "inversify-express-utils": "^6.4.3",
- ```
  nodejs : 18+
  ```
- MacOs

## Stack trace

### Current Behavior

```
For any first container config that is imported and its last router is giving this error:
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)
```

Comment: This is what is referred to as a "wall of code" and shows no effort to distill the code down to what you think is causing the error and ask a specific question about that.  That is probably why you've received no info since posted.

Comment: I tried and seems specific issue with inversify in general, can't find out the root cause yet. I have to first get what was the actual issue (figuring out the actual issue was itself an effort else I could have just posted the API is not working I tried to distill down where and when) so was wondering if anyone have found a resolution if any, also have raised the same issue with them. If I get any will sure to update the question or give answer.  

I tried with udpating error middleware, passing different config, used in different set of repository all were having the same issue

Comment: There is not an ability to follow code execution for even one particular incoming http request here so it's hard for us to do much here.  The root cause of *"Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"* is when more than one piece of code attempts to send a response to the same request.  The second time you try to send a response to a request that has already had a response sent, you get this error.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122272/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client/52122527#52122527) for info.