# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client with unique return

Tags: javascript, node.js

I dont have a minimal idea of happen. I have two function similar, but one of then don't work and crash my application.

```
const { json } = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

const getCategories = async (req, res) => {
  let connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 1,
  });

  const [categories] = await connection.query(
    "SELECT category FROM `training` WHERE name IS NULL"
  );
  res.status(200).json(categories);
};
module.exports = {
  getCategories,
};
```

Error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\Dev\academia-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\Dev\academia-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (F:\Dev\academia-api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at getTrainings (F:\Dev\academia-api\src\controllers\RecordController.js:69:21)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My other function work fine

```
const { json } = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
require("dotenv").config();

const getCoach = async (req, res) => {
  let connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 1,
  });

  const body = req.body;

  const [coach] = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM `coach`");

  return res.status(200).json(coach);
};

module.exports = {
  getCoach,
};
```

Eu nao tenho a minima ideia do porque isso esta acontecendo. As funcoes sao praticamente iguais e nao e so possuem um retorno de dados o que por regra nao causaria o problema de headers. Alguem ja viu algo parecido e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: The error seems to say it's coming from `getTrainings`, but the code your showing is saying -> `getCategories`

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your entire question or try [pt.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain the relevant code to see what's going on, but this general error and some of its causes are described here: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122272/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client/52122527#52122527)